# Enhanced Auth Dialog from Open Graph Beta not working. Still shows the old Auth Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, custom-action

I'm trying to publish custom actions to a user's Facebook stream. I need to request the "publish_actions" permission from the user. My understanding is I can only request this permission as a Test user of my app when using the Enhanced Auth Dialog. Except it's still showing the normal(old) Auth Dialog.

I think I've done everything I need to enable this. I've got an Aggregation for my custom action and I've checked the Advanced app settings. Enhanced Auth Dialog is set to Enabled.

Any ideas?

```
FB.login(function(response){
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // The user has granted the "publish_action" permission
    }
    else {
        // The user has declined to grant the "publish_actions" permission.
    }
},{"scope": "publish_actions"});
```

Comment: have you enabled the new auth dialog from your apps settings?

Comment: yeah +1 on this, don't know what extra 'setting 'is required to display the new dialog.